# WPF. Ошибка при инициализации компонентов в MainPage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, исключения

Есть следующий замл код:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0.4,1.2">
    <Button Content="Parse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253" Height="91" FontSize="36" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}"/>
    <DataGrid Margin="10,373,10,10.2" ItemsControl.ItemsSource="{Binding Source = InformationAboutSong}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Thumbnail" Width="200">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Song name" Width="260" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist name" Width="260" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    
    <TextBox x:Name="PlayListId_textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="104,153,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter playlist id" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="667" FontSize="20"/>

    <DataGrid Margin="10,191,0,369.2" ItemsControl.ItemsSource="{Binding Source = InformationAboutPlaylist}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Playlist thumbnail" Width="300">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Playlist description" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Дата контекст используется из модели другого проекта (на проект добавлены линки). С помощью замл файла App -   `<Application  ... ... Startup="App_Startup"`>

VM выглядит следующим образом :

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _link;

    public string Link
    {
        get { return _link; }
        set { _link = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("InformationAboutSong");
            OnPropertyChanged("InformationAboutPlaylist");
        }
    }

    public BindingList<Track> InformationAboutSong { get; set; }
    public BindingList<Playlist> InformationAboutPlaylist { get; set; }

    public ICommand ButtonClick
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
            {
                MainModel mm = new MainModel();

                InformationAboutSong = mm.GetSongInfo(Link);
                InformationAboutPlaylist = mm.GetPlaylistInfo(Link);

            });
        }

    }
}
```

И при запуске проекта в cs InitializeComponent() ловлю следующую ошибку :

> "....InvalidOperationException: Операция недопустима, когда ItemsSource используется. Вместо этого получите доступ и измените элементы с помощью ItemsControl.ItemsSource....."

Answer (score 3):

У вас пропущен `DataGrid.Columns` у второй таблицы.

Вот, поправил разметку

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Link}" Margin="5" ToolTip="Enter playlist id" Width="500" FontSize="20" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Content="Parse" Margin="5" Padding="10,5" FontSize="20" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding InformationAboutSong}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Thumbnail" Width="200">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Song name" Width="260" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist name" Width="260" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding InformationAboutPlaylist}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Playlist thumbnail" Width="300">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Playlist description" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Учитесь использовать `Grid` и `StackPanel`/`WrapPanel`, иначе война с марджинами превратится в бесконечный поток мучений.

#### И еще немного советов

`BindingList` замените на `ObservableCollection` и реализуйте свойства по шаблону, как это обычно делается при реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

*Как я понял, `BindingList` вам от WinForms достался, в WPF его заменяет `ObservableCollection`.*

```
private string _link;
private ObservableCollection<Track> _informationAboutSong;
private ObservableCollection<Playlist> _informationAboutPlaylist;

public string Link
{
    get => _link;
    set
    {
        _link = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Link));
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<Track> InformationAboutSong
{
    get => _informationAboutSong;
    set
    {
        _informationAboutSong = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InformationAboutSong));
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<Playlist> InformationAboutPlaylist
{
    get => _informationAboutPlaylist;
    set
    {
        _informationAboutPlaylist = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InformationAboutPlaylist));
    }
}
```

---

По команде, возмите вот такой класс, перенаправляющий логику команды

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) 
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Он поддерживает `CommandParameter`, и если будете использовать `CanExecute`, то узнаете, что он вызывает `CanExecute` автоматически при любом событии ввода. Не я его придумал, я его стащил из [документации по MVVM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic), и слегка причесал.

Сейчас ваша команда инициализируется заново каждый раз, когда кто-либо обращается в геттеру свойства команды, чтобы этого не происходило, можно использовать "ленивую" инициализацию, которая произойдет только один раз при первом обращении к команде.

```
private ICommand _buttonClick;

public ICommand ButtonClick => _buttonClick ?? (_buttonClick = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    MainModel mm = new MainModel();

    InformationAboutSong = mm.GetSongInfo(Link);
    InformationAboutPlaylist = mm.GetPlaylistInfo(Link);
}, parameter => Link?.Length > 0));
```

Если у вас .NET Core и C# 8, то синтаксис будет немного поприятнее

```
public ICommand ButtonClick => _buttonClick ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    MainModel mm = new MainModel();

    InformationAboutSong = mm.GetSongInfo(Link);
    InformationAboutPlaylist = mm.GetPlaylistInfo(Link);
}, parameter => Link?.Length > 0);
```

И `ButtonClick` - странное название для команды, назовите ее `ParseCommand`

**Обновил:** добавил `CanExecute` `parameter => Link?.Length > 0`

---

Если вот это не заработает

```
InformationAboutSong = mm.GetSongInfo(Link);
```

то попробуйте вот так

```
InformationAboutSong = new ObservableCollection<Track>(mm.GetSongInfo(Link));
```

Comment: Ошибка осталась всё та же что и в самом начале. 
"System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: '"Добавление значения в коллекцию типа "System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection" вызвало исключение.": номер строки "35" и позиция в строке "23".'
и т.д.
Я не понимаю с чем это связано.
Так что даже если ошибки дальше и есть, я не могу их отследить, т.к. на этом программа останавливается. 
p.s. я проделал всё что вы написали.

Comment: Я всего лишь новичек, и мало что понимаю, но BindigList мне не от WinForms достался.(вообще им там никогда не пользовался 0_0) 
Просто где то увидел и стал использовать.

Comment: А как данный ответ должен помочь человеку с ошибкой, которая гласит о том, что задан `ItemsSource` и итем контрола в XAML разом (нечто: `<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding}"><некий объект></ListBox>` )?

Comment: @nikitamanzhosov обновил ответ, у вас неправильно была размечена вторая `DataGrid`. И учитесь использовать марджины как я, в таком варианте интерфейс получится "резиновый", можно изменять размер окна, и ничего не будет ломаться. И с марджинами не будет мучений.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у него пропущена секция `DataGrid.Columns` у второй таблицы, я дал исправленную разметку

Comment: @nikitamanzhosov добавил `Text="{Binding Link}"` для текстбокса в разметку, надеюсь я правильно понял, как вы хотите. чтобы работало. Добавил `CanExecute`

Comment: Ну вот, уже лучше, только акцент должен быть на решение проблемы, а не на дополнительных "советах". Сейчас же такое чувство, что у человека полностью надо переделать приложения для того, чтобы решить проблему, описанную в вопросе, думайте о будущих читателях, ведь найдя в гугле этот вопрос человек придется потратить время на поиск нужной инфы...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ справедливо, исправил.

Comment: @nikitamanzhosov вам помог мой ответ? если да, отметьте его пожалуйста принятым.